# How can I set the attributed text while having no placeholder text?

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, nsattributedstring, swift, xcode6.3

Code that worked in Xcode 6.2 no longer works and I'm having trouble figuring out how to fix it. String attributes are now ignored unless I set default text. Here's what I've got right now:

```
    let font = UIFont(name: "Arial-BoldMT", size: 42.0)!
    let textStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle().mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
    textStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    let textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var shadow = NSShadow()
    shadow.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0,2.0)

    var attr = [String:NSObject]()

    attr = [
        NSFontAttributeName: font,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: textStyle,
        NSShadowAttributeName: shadow
    ]

    let placeholderText = NSAttributedString(string: "", attributes: attr)
    textView.attributedText = placeholderText
```

Comment: Still works perfectly fine for me. What exactly "doesn't work"? Expected results? Actual results? Im also surprised that you are trying to see attributes applied to an empty String?! And where are all of your variables (font, textColor etc) defined?

Comment: I've updated the question for clarity, and yes it turns out the empty string was the problem. Got misled by errors and thought it had to do with the attributes. So I've tweaked the question — how can I set attributed text without having a placeholder string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the placeHolderText to `NSAttributedString(string: " ", attributes: attr)` you can then change the `UITextView`'s text by changing its `text` property and the new text will have all the same attributes.
I hope that answers your question.